# eslintrc type-safety in VSCode using jsdoc annotations importing typescript declarations

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, jsdoc

How do I get VSCode to check syntax of `.eslintrc.js` and do autocompletion ? I was able to use the following structure for a js config file that follows a custom syntax defined by my own app, but when I try to apply the same trick to `Linter.BaseConfig` imported from 'eslint', it doesn't do anything.

```
/** @typedef {import("eslint").Linter.BaseConfig} BaseConfig */
/** @param {BaseConfig} c */ // ne fonctionne pas
function castBaseConfig(c) {return c}
module.exports = castBaseConfig({
  env: {browser: false, es2019: true, node: true},
  ignorePatterns: ["dist", "jsdoc", "out", "out2", "public"],
  extends: "eslint:recommended",
  parserOptions: {ecmaVersion: "latest"},
  // etc
})
```

Note that `node_modules/@types/eslint/index.d.ts` contains `export namespace Linter {interface BaseConfig {...}}` with field definitions for env, parserOptions, plugins, rules (via `HasRules`), etc... so it looks like it should work. It's not a file lookup issue about node_modules or index.d.ts, because tooltip for `type BaseConfig` says it expands to `Linter.BaseConfig<Linter.RulesRecord, Linter.RulesRecord>`, but no type-checking seems to be happening, and no type-specific completions work.

For my other file where I use that trick, the type definition imported using `/** @typedef {import("../lib/config").MultiConfig} MultiConfig */` is correctly applied: e.g. it complains if `port` is a string instead of a number, or if a required property is missing, or if an unknown property is present, and Ctrl+space offers the remaining unspecified properties for the appropriate context.

Could it be related to differences in the definitions ? E.g. `interface` vs `type`.

Answer (score 0):

The other difference between `.eslintrc.js` and my other js file that is already checked, is that the latter was listed in `tsconfig.json`. Adding `.eslintrc.js` to `tsconfig.json` causes the checking to happen.

But then, `BaseConfig` was not the correct type to use, because it is missing `ignorePatterns` ("Object literal may only specify known properties"). So at first I extended BaseConfig in this manner : `/** @param {BaseConfig & {ignorePatterns:string[]}} c */`. But then I found that `/** @param {Config} */` does the job. Also the @typedef can be merged into the @param like this. Finally, I found out that there is another version of those decls found in npm package `@typescript-eslint/utils` (formerly `@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils`), that are supposed to be more correct and better maintained. So the end result is :

```
/** @param {import("@typescript-eslint/utils/dist/ts-eslint/Linter").Linter.Config} c */
function castConfig(c) {return c}
module.exports = castConfig({
  // your conf goes here
})
```

Alternately, you can skip the dummy function, but in that case, you have to split the export instead, because @type is ignored on `module.exports =`, which makes it not much shorter :

```
/** @type {import("@typescript-eslint/utils/dist/ts-eslint/Linter").Linter.Config} c */
var c = castConfig({
  // your conf goes here
})
module.exports = c
```

See Also:

- https://github.com/eslint/rfcs/pull/50
- https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2153

TODO: also typecheck specific rulesets. E.g. use `@typedef` to load type definitions from `eslint-plugin-something` and pass them as parameter in the `Config<>` type.